# How to pass start date and end date in the URL based on a day?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add the start date and end date in the URL. How to pass `start_date :2017-11-11` and `End_date: 2017-11-14` in the URL based on a day ?

I wrote some code and able to get a list of days between date and able to print date between a start date and end date. But when I pass the date in the URL, It's taking only one day and I need the result as below :

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

dateformat = '%Y-%m-%d'
startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-11-11', dateformat)
enddate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-11-13', dateformat)
date_array = \
  (startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (enddate-startdate).days + 1))
print("Number of days", (enddate-startdate).days)

for date_object in date_array:
    print("List of date", date_object.strftime(dateformat))

nextday = (startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
print( "Next day", nextday.strftime(dateformat))

link = 'https://xyx?start_date='+ startdate.strftime(dateformat) + '&end_date=' + nextday.strftime(dateformat)
print("print link", link)
```

Output from current code:

```
Number of days 2
List of date 2017-11-11
List of date 2017-11-12
List of date 2017-11-13
Next day 2017-11-12
print link https://xyx?start_date=2017-11-11&end_date=2017-11-12
```

Expected output:

```
Number of days 2
List of date 2017-11-11
List of date 2017-11-12
List of date 2017-11-13
Next day 2017-11-12
print link https://xyx?start_date=2017-11-11&end_date=2017-11-12
print link https://xyx?start_date=2017-11-12&end_date=2017-11-13
```

Comment: Are the lines `link = ...` and `print("print link", link)` supposed to be part of the `for date_object in date_array` loop?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should be under for loop.but when I add those two lines under for loop I am getting error : TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

I tried it another way as below :
             for date_object in date_array:
                 print("List of date", date_object.strftime(dateformat))
          link = 'https://xyx?start_date='+ date_object.strftime(dateformat) + 
                 '&end_date=' + date_object.strftime(dateformat)
          print("print link", link)

             output:

Comment: I tried it another way as below :
               ' for date_object in date_array:
                    print("List of date", date_object.strftime(dateformat))
             link = 'https://xyx?start_date='+ date_object.strftime(dateformat) + 
                    '&end_date=' + date_object.strftime(dateformat)
             print("print link", link)'

Comment: ' output:
                 print link https://xyx?start_date=2017-11-11&end_date=2017-11-11
                 print link https://xyx?start_date=2017-11-12&end_date=2017-11-12
                 print link https://xyx?start_date=2017-11-13&end_date=2017-11-13'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

dateformat = '%Y-%m-%d'
startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-11-11', dateformat)
enddate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-11-13', dateformat)
date_array = [startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (enddate - startdate).days + 1)]
print("Number of days", (enddate - startdate).days)
for date_object in date_array:
    print("List of date", date_object.strftime(dateformat))

nextday = (startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
print("Next day", nextday.strftime(dateformat))

link = 'https://xyx?start_date=' + startdate.strftime(dateformat) + '&end_date=' + nextday.strftime(dateformat)
print("print link", link)
print("*"*20)
for i in range(len(date_array)):
    if i + 1 < len(date_array):
        link = 'https://xyx?start_date=' + date_array[i].strftime(dateformat) + '&end_date=' + date_array[i+1].strftime(dateformat)
        print (link)
```

Output is:

```
Number of days 2
List of date 2017-11-11
List of date 2017-11-12
List of date 2017-11-13
Next day 2017-11-12
print link https://xyx?start_date=2017-11-11&end_date=2017-11-12
********************
https://xyx?start_date=2017-11-11&end_date=2017-11-12
https://xyx?start_date=2017-11-12&end_date=2017-11-13
```

Comment: Glad to help you Jigna! :)